# Formula for perimeter of a figure formed by cutting 4 inscribed congruent figures.

Tags: geometry

The area of a cross formed by cutting 4 congruent squares from a large square is $20$.  If the cross is a regular polygon, its perimeter equals:
a.)$24$
b.)$48$
c.)$64$
d.)$12\sqrt{5}$
e.)$16\sqrt{5}$

Answer (score 1):

A picture will tell you everything. The "regular polygon" part is intended to tell you that all sides of the cross are of equal length.

The picture will tell you that the cross is made up of $5$ squares. The total area is $20$, so each of the $5$ squares has area $4$, and therefore side $2$. Now you know enough to find the perimeter.

There is no need for formulas, just add up. But you might notice something nice. The cross was made by cutting out $2\times 2$ squares from the corners of a $6\times 6$ square. How is the perimeter of the cross related to the perimeter of the original square?